# How to use Celery in Java web Application

Tags: java, struts2, celery

Ours is a Java webapplication developed on Struts2 framework with Hibernate 3.5 ORM.  We want to run few tasks (scheduled & unscheduled) Asynchronously. In google search i found  Celery Library, a asynchronous task queue/job queue which focuses on real-time operation and supports Scheduling as well.

Can i use this library in our existing java project?  Do i need to add any other dependencies for this library. Please suggest me a solution for this.

The tasks that we want to execute Asynchronously for our project includes sending emails, generating csv files from the collected data etc.,

Answer (score 1):

I use Spring Services for this.

```
@Service
public class MyAsynchronousService {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 6 * * *")
    public void runDailyAtSixAClock() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Spring is working well as DI when using already Struts2 and Hibernate. Just use the struts2-spring-plugin.

Comment: we are not using Springs frame work in our webapp, so using struts2-spring plugin will be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Celery is. Is it not Python library?

In Java there is a number of ways to organise your scheduled jobs:

- Quartz
- @Scheduled
- Spring Batch

Comment: Yes, Celery is a Python library. Thanks for the info on Java scheduled jobs libraries..

Answer (score 1):

We are using celery in conjunction with a C#/.Net app. Celery has good support for accepting tasks and querying task status over HTTP, which is what we use. See the Celery HTTP Gateway example app for more information:

https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/celery_http_gateway